# Using gdb/lldb to debug apache segfault

Tags: apache-2.4, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am currently running an apache webserver on a macOS with an M1 chip. Recently I have been receiving some segmentation fault which is accompanied by empty response errors in the website. After looking online I have found the common suggestion is to coredump and perform a backtrace to track the root cause of the problem. However, when I try installing GDB, I get an error from homebrew, which after looking into, is because M1 chips do not support GDB. Instead I was recommended to use lldb which, however, seems to have problems attaching to apache processes. The error I am receiving while trying to attach to the process is "Failed to attach to process not allowed to attach to process". I am coming to this community wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to debugging this segfault issue because I seem to be facing heavy resistance with lldb.